# Integral bounded by curves

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Calculate the integral
$$
\int_{B} f(x,y) \, d(x,y), 
$$
where $f(x,y) = xy$ and $B$ is bounded by the perpendiculars $x=0$ and $x=2$, by the curve $y=2$ and $y=x^2+2$.

I'm not sure if the function $y=x^2+2$ is there for confusion because $y=2$ is below it, or if it's just the area that $y=2$ and $y=x^2+2$ enclose in the interval $[0, 2]$?

In case it is not so, the integral would be
$$
\int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{2} xy \, dy \, dx,
$$
and if so, then the integral would be
$$
\int_{0}^{2} \int_{2}^{x^2+2} xy \, dy \, dx
$$

What do you guys think about this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That looks right

Comment: but what do you think is the right way?

Comment: I don’t understand your question

Comment: Which is the right way to interpret the task? is it integral 1 or 2?

Comment: Whoops, I missed the first integral. The second one looks right. You can try plotting these functions to make sure.